# Android Studio Invoke Red Lightbulb

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and I love using the little red light bulb for things like define a method. When I click on a red error it appears.

Mostly it works fine but sometimes it disappears too quickly to click on and sometimes it does not appear at all.

Is there a shortcut key to make it appear ? Or what is the name of the lightbulb so that I can Google for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The lightbulb shortcut is alt+enter "Use the suggested quick fix."

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Comment: Thank you Alt Enter does work even if the light bulb is not showing.

Comment: Dang - but I still want to see the lightbulb.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you can do

```
option + return
```